# How can I disable a SpriteKit node touch event and then enable it after 25 seconds to be touched and moved to next scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How can I disable a SpriteKit node touch event and then enable it after 25 seconds so that when the node is touched it will take the user to the next scene?

I am setting up a GameScene that plays an audio file for 25 seconds and then after that I want the user to be able to click on a SpriteKit Node that will take the user to the next Scene.  The problem is the node cannot be hidden.  It needs to be visible and but disable and then visible and enabled for touch after 25 seconds.

```
    if nextButton.contains(location) {
        if nextButton.isHidden == true {
            nextButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        } else {
            goToScene(scene: getNextScene()!)
        }
```

I have used this code for when the SPriteKit Node has been able to be hidden, but this time the Node must be visible the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of this, your GameScene is what handles the touch events,  so when you are playing your audio, you should do something like this:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = false
let audio = SKAudioNode()
audio.run{
    SKAction.group([SKAction.play, 
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.wait(forDuration:25),
            SKAction.run({self.userInteractionEnabled = true})
        ])
    )
}
self.addChild(audio)
```

If you are using playSound action

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = false
let audio = SKSpriteNode()
audio.run{ 
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("mySound",true),
        SKAction.run({self.userInteractionEnabled = true})
    ])
}
```

Basically what this does is sets a delay action to enable touch after the sound finishes.

Comment: I tried using the first one but I still got an error.  Should that code be under the didMove fucntion?

Comment: Where are you doing it now?

Comment: Under the override func didMove